# how to find global loading in react query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

is there anyway to find out if isLoading state is changing globally for all api calls in react query in one place or set an interceptor to find out whether isLoading state changes globally?

```js
      <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
<App/>
</QueryClientProvider>
```

Comment: Why would `isLoading` change globally?

Answer (score 1):

`useIsFetching({ predicate: query => query.state.status === 'loading' })`

should do the trick.